# Publish Winform to Azure

Tags: winforms, azure

In the past I have only used my WinForm apps in my office and have published to a server on LAN using Click Once. Is it possible to publish WinForm apps to Azure using Click Once. I have an account there.

Comment: Are you looking for instructions on putting your ClickOnce files in Azure so that users of the application can download it from there?

Comment: Found this and it works. Thanks.https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: :) I would've pointed you to the same link :) :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is instructions it works.

```
https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-     deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/
```